# PostgreSQL: Could not open file for reading. Permission denied. SQL state: 42501

Tags: database, postgresql, csv

```
COPY dept 
FROM '/media/rayhan/CSE/PostgreSQL/csv_file/dept.csv' 
DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

Running this query produce following error. I've changed the file extension from .csv to .txt, but same error occurs. Help me to solve this problem. I'm using `PostgreSQL` `version 9.5.12`. Thanks in advance.

> ERROR:  could not open file
>   "/media/rayhan/CSE/PostgreSQL/csv_file/dept.txt" for reading:
>   Permission denied

********** Error **********

> ERROR: could not open file
>   "/media/rayhan/CSE/PostgreSQL/csv_file/dept.csv" for reading:
>   Permission denied SQL state: 42501

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that, The PostgreSQL process doesn't have the permission to access your "csv", find the username which started the PostgreSQL Service and then give the read permission to PG service user "using chmod" at Linux level.

If still facing issue then, change the permission as below:

```
chmod a+rX /media
chmod a+rX /media/rayhan
chmod a+rX /media/rayhan/CSE
chmod a+rX /media/rayhan/CSE/PostgreSQL
chmod a+rX /media/rayhan/CSE/PostgreSQL/csv_file
chmod a+rX /media/rayhan/CSE/PostgreSQL/csv_file/dept.csv
```

Now try again to use COPY.

Comment: Running those commands show "chmod: changing permissions of '/media': Operation not permitted"

Comment: Using `sudo chmod` the problem gets solved. Thanks a lot @Vivek. :D

Comment: If u find my solution is useful you can vote up and mark this as answers

Answer (score 4):

I was getting same issue when I was connecting from client to remote postgres server. I changed **copy** to **\copy** and it worked.

In your case it would be

\COPY dept 
FROM '/media/rayhan/CSE/PostgreSQL/csv_file/dept.csv' 
DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;